# Counting Rows with LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with counting rows using LEFT JOIN ..
So i have 2 tables (domains, chat) and I want to extract for each domain, the total number of chats, the number of open chats and the number of closed chats. the common column is "domain"

Here is my code:

```
$getDomains = $DB->query("
SELECT 
dom.id as domainID, dom.name as domainName, dom.domain as url, dom.gmt, dom.opening_hours, 
COUNT(t1.id) as chats, 
COUNT(t2.id) as opened_chats, 
COUNT(t3.id) as closed_chats

FROM domains dom

LEFT OUTER JOIN chat t1 ON t1.domain=dom.domain
LEFT OUTER JOIN chat t2 ON t2.domain=dom.domain AND t2.status=1
LEFT OUTER JOIN chat t3 ON t3.domain=dom.domain AND t3.status=3

WHERE dom.account_id = ".$userInfo['account_id']." GROUP BY dom.domain") or die (mysqli_error($DB));
```

In chat column i have 6 chats ( 3 opened, 3 closed ).

And instead of:

- All chats: 6
- Opened chats: 3
- Closed chats: 3

The result is:

- All Chats: 54
- Opened chats: 54
- closed chats: 54

Anyone cand help me? i can't understand where is the problem...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query insted of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`,

```
$getDomains = $DB->query("
    SELECT 
    dom.id as domainID, dom.name as domainName, dom.domain as url, dom.gmt, dom.opening_hours, 
    (select count(t1.id) from chat as t1 where t1.domain=dom.domain) as chats,
    (select count(t2.id) from chat as t1 where t2.domain=dom.domain AND t2.status=1) as opened_chats,
    (select count(t3.id) from chat as t1 where t3.domain=dom.domain AND t3.status=3) as closed_chats

    FROM domains dom

    WHERE dom.account_id = ".$userInfo['account_id']." GROUP BY dom.domain") or die (mysqli_error($DB));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead use a single join

```
SELECT dom.*, 
       COUNT(t.id) as chats, 
       sum(t.status=1) as opened_chats, 
       sum(t.status=3) as closed_chats
FROM domains dom
LEFT OUTER JOIN chat t ON t.domain=dom.domain
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  dom....,
  COUNT(*) as chats,
  SUM(chat.status=1) as opened_chats,
  SUM(chat.status=3) as closed_chats
FROM
  domains dom
LEFT JOIN
  chat ON chat.domain = dom.domain
WHERE dom.account_id = ? 
GROUP BY dom.domain
```

Comment: Still problem if i have more rows... i fix it, thanks